# Python code mutes whole video instead of sliding a song. What shall I do?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, moviepy, ffmpeg-python

I am trying to separate a song into 4 parts and slide the parts in random parts of a video. The problem with my code is that the final output video is muted. I want to play parts of the song at random intervals and while the song is playing the original video shall be muted. Thanks to everyone who helps

```
import random
from moviepy.editor import *

def split_audio_into_parts(mp3_path, num_parts):
    audio = AudioFileClip(mp3_path)
    duration = audio.duration
    part_duration = duration / num_parts

    parts = []
    for i in range(num_parts):
        start_time = i * part_duration
        end_time = start_time + part_duration if i < num_parts - 1 else duration
        part = audio.subclip(start_time, end_time)
        parts.append(part)

    return parts

def split_video_into_segments(video_path, num_segments):
    video = VideoFileClip(video_path)
    duration = video.duration
    segment_duration = duration / num_segments

    segments = []
    for i in range(num_segments):
        start_time = i * segment_duration
        end_time = start_time + segment_duration if i < num_segments - 1 else duration
        segment = video.subclip(start_time, end_time)
        segments.append(segment)

    return segments

def insert_audio_into_segments(segments, audio_parts):
    modified_segments = []
    for segment, audio_part in zip(segments, audio_parts):
        audio_part = audio_part.volumex(0)  # Mute the audio part
        modified_segment = segment.set_audio(audio_part)
        modified_segments.append(modified_segment)

    return modified_segments

def combine_segments(segments):
    final_video = concatenate_videoclips(segments)
    return final_video

# Example usage
mp3_file_path = "C:/Users/Kris/PycharmProjects/videoeditingscript124234/DENKATA - Podvodnica Demo (1).mp3"
video_file_path = "C:/Users/Kris/PycharmProjects/videoeditingscript124234/family.guy.s21e13.1080p.web.h264-cakes[eztv.re].mkv"
num_parts = 4

audio_parts = split_audio_into_parts(mp3_file_path, num_parts)
segments = split_video_into_segments(video_file_path, num_parts)
segments = insert_audio_into_segments(segments, audio_parts)
final_video = combine_segments(segments)
final_video.write_videofile("output.mp4", codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

I tried entering most stuff into chatGPT and asking questions around forums but without sucess, so lets hope I can see my solution here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.